# does variables in shared preferences share accross applications?

Tags: android

I want to share variable between two android application so I stored it in  shared preference but when I reinstalled the application that store the variable the second application didn't see the variable, what is the best way to share variable between two application and dealing with situation when one of them will be reinstalled

I used this code

```
SharedPreferences globals_prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("globals_prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SharedPreferences` in one application is stored as a `prefs.xml` file in a separate folder dedicated for you app in the Android File System. So when you uninstall an app, this folder also is deleted, thereby, all `Preferences` made by your app is removed. So a better way is to use Files to store it in the sdCard.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later.

From android dev documents
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

File or sqlite database on **public directory** would do the trick when sharing data

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall an app shared preference and internal cache is wiped out, so the only way is to use external storage.